# Rails: Creating a simple Timer inside a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to programming and need some help to create a basic timer in Ruby on Rails which can be started and stopped trough a button click in a view. For each stopped time a time-entry should get saved inside the database to the corresponding `task`.

I actually don't need code examples but some help where to start (code would be nice tho'.).

What the view looks like:

[image: view example]

As I wrote, when the `Start` button got pressed, a `time-entry` (containing the start time as a UNIX timestamp) should be  saved to the databse and belong to the current viewed task. When clicking `Stop` the current time, again, should get saved as UNIX timestamp. The next click on `Start` should create a new `time-entry` and so on.

I don't want to use any gems if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's exactly my problem: I don't really know where to start. I don't want anyone to just solve my issue but a conecpt of where to start. Something like a roadmap I can follow along to understand the basic conecpt.

Comment: You can do a research for that, starting from basic ruby-on-rails tutorials. There are plenty of resources for that if you do enough research

Comment: A task has one time-entry or can have multiple?

Comment: It should have multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, there are many ways how to approach this. I suggest this (simpler) approach which should also teach you how everything works in Ruby on Rails.

Update it in the controller every time a button is pressed. Create new methods **start_time** and **stop_time** in your *tasks_controller.rb* where you update the time. Update the *routes.rb* file so you have the paths to the methods. In the view (show.html.erb in this case), create two buttons that redirect to the controller like so:

`<%= link_to "Start", start_time_task_path %>`
`<%= link_to "Stop", stop_time_task_path %>`

Finally, in the controller methods, do something like `Task.update(start_time: Time.now)` (depending on your database structure. And you're done.

Another approach could be creating two forms for **Task**, each of which represents one of the actions. You could also track the time with Javascript and send both times in once "Stop" is clicked.

I hope this answers your questions. I've tried putting as little code as possible, so to proceed you should try reading the Rails [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) or following a simple video tutorial online where the MVC flow is illustrated.

Comment: Thanks for actually helping! I'll give it a try.